# How to identify the RedisValue from key dynamically net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, stackexchange.redis

I'm new to Redis. I was doing get all keys and iterating key and get the value.

Here is the code:

```
        var keys = Connection.GetServer("localhost", 6379).Keys();
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = db.StringGet(key);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Got exception as

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: 'WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value'

db.StringGet(key) method returns only string. I was looking for dynamic `redisValueType.kindof<T>`.

So, is there any method to identify the **RedisValue** type ? To get the value based on the type?

Answer (score -1):

When you call this method :

> var keys = Connection.GetServer("localhost", 6379).Keys();

You will get `IEnamarable<RedisKey>`, So use `key.ToString()` like

> string[] keysArr = keys.Select(key => key.ToString()).ToArray();

to cast `RedisKey` to `string`

`db.StringGet` Method want `string` as parameter, So you have to get string to this method.
This method will return you string also you have to Deserilize it to your model use the code below :

```
var json = db.GetString(key);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            return default;

var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
```

- `T` is the your model in generic so when you want to call this method you can use it like this:

  ```
  public T TryGetItem<T>(string key)
  {
     var json = db.GetString(key);

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
         return default;

     var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);

     return  item;
  }
  ```

Call it like below:

> var result = TryGetItem(key);

Comment: Thank you for quick response! from this line of code "db.StringGet(key);"  got the exception.